# Could I declare a table of bits?

Tags: c++, fortran, communication, mpi, bit

I am building an MPI application. In order to reduce the size of the messages being transferred, I am thinking of having tables of "bits" to represent `bool` tables (since the `bool` value can take only one of two values: `true` or `false`). It is important in my case since the communication is the main performance bottleneck in my application.

Is it possible to create this kind of table? Does this datatype exist in the MPI API?

Comment: I don't really understand the requirement.

Comment: I presume by MPI you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface

Comment: Why dont you send ints, in which you encode your bits?

Answer (score 4):

In C++ [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) or [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) can be useful to manage a number of bits. Choose the later if the size of the bitset isn't fixed. AFAIK MPI uses `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Rec` for inter process communication. How you serialize your output and send them through those interfaces is another matter as neither of the two types is supported by Boost.Serialization.

Comment: A good generic answer, but I'm betting the questioner is more interested in the MPI interface.

Comment: @MarkRansom I hope OP is aware how to use user-defined types with MPI. Otherwise the whole question seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tag in the original question, I assume you are using a mix of Fortran and C++. MPI binding for Fortran has the datatype MPI_LOGICAL, which you can readily use in your message passing calls. I am not aware of such type for MPI C binding. As suggested by PlasmaHH, sending integers might work for you in that case.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Derived_Data_Types

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, the shortest MPI datatype is MPI_BYTE, you can't create a type that's just a bit.  (The fortran bindings have MPI_LOGICAL which corresponds to the local logical type, but that almost always corresponds to an int or maybe a byte, not a bit).

Now, that's not necessarily a problem; if you had a bit array you could just round up to the next whole number of bytes, and send that, and just ignore the last few bits.  (which is pretty much what you'd have to do in your table creation anyway). But I have some questions.

How large are your messages?   And what's your networking?  Are you *sure* you're bandwidth limited, rather than latency limited?

If your messages are smallish (say under an MB), then you're likely dominated by latency of messages, not bandwidth, and reducing message size won't help.  (You can estimate this using pingpong tests - say in the [Intel MPI benchmarks](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mpi-benchmarks/) - to see at what sizes your effective bandwidth levels off).  If that's the regime you're in, then this will likely make things worse, not better, as communication won't speed up but additional cost of indexing into a bit array will likely slow things down.

On the other hand, if you're sending large messages (say MB sized) and/or you're memory limited, this could be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would transfer your bits into an array of integers.

I will answer in regard to the `FORTRAN` language.
You can use the intrinsic bit operations to move the bits back and forth.

Also to clearify, you should not use the `FORTRAN` type `LOGICAL` as it is an 4-byte variable just as regular integers.
Use these functions:

```
BIT_SIZE(I)
IBCLR(I, POS) ! Set to 0 in variable I at position POS
IBSET(I, POS) ! Set to 1 in variable I at position POS
BTEST(I, POS) ! To test if bit at POS is 1
```

Then do a normal transfer in whatever type you are dealing with. You can add tags in the MPI communication to let the receiver know that it is a variable that should be handled bitwise.
This should limit your communication, but requires packing of the data and outpackaging as well. In any case you could also just transfer all your BOOL tables to this scheme.

But it should be noticed that your BOOL tables have to be extensively big to see any effect, how large are we talking?